# How to merge two DataTable don't create new row?

Tags: c#

I have two data table first one is 'dataTable1' which values are :

q  | Student | Alumni

---+---------+-------

q1 |    2    |   4

q2 |    3    |   2

q3 |    4    |   1

And the second one is 'dataTable2'  values are:

q  | Student | Alumni | Employee

---+---------+--------+---------

q1 |    1    |   1    |   3

q2 |    5    |   3    |

q3 |    2    |   2    |   2

now I want to merge these two tables which are actually performed like 'Add' operation

q  | Student | Alumni | Employee

---+---------+--------+---------

q1 |    3    |   5    |   3

q2 |    8    |   5    |

q3 |    6    |   3    |   2

```
dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2);
```

Comment: Overwrite same entries or append them ?

Comment: sorry sir I don't get you @Isaac. Actually I want to merge these two tables where these two tables has fixed row

Answer (score 0):

Let's modify the table with the greater column count (modify dt2 to add the values from dt1):

```
//make it easy to look things up in dataTable1:
dataTable1.PrimaryKey = new [] { dataTable1.Columns["q"] };

//loop every row of datatable2, lookup the same row from table 1 and add its values:
foreach(DataRow ro in dataTable2.Rows){
  var ro1 = dataTable1.Rows.Find(ro["q"]);
  for(int x = 1; x<dataTable1.Columns.Count; x++)
    ro[x] = (int)ro[x] + (int)ro1[x];
}
```

This code makes a few assumptions, of course:

- that the datatable1 row always exists to match to dataTable2
- that the columns in the two tables are in the same order
- that there are fewer or same number of columns in 1 compared to 2

If these things aren't true you'll have to work around them:

- check the Find result for null before you use it
- use column names instead of number indexes
- x loop should use whichever table has fewer columns in the x < table.Columns.Count

If your tables always have the rows in the same order also you can skip the PrimaryKey/Find logic and just access them positionally:

```
for(int y = 0; y < dataTable2.Rows.Count; y++){
  for(int x = 1; x<dataTable1.Columns.Count; x++)
    dataTable2.Rows[y][x] = (int)dataTable1.Rows[y][x] + (int)dataTable2.Rows[y][x];
}
```

Comment: your last solution is almost appropriate for my code but there is a problem that two tables don't have same number of column but these columns are the same order and the rows too

Comment: Doesn't matter that they don't have the same number of columns; loop against the shorter one (I did) so you don't get IndexOutOfRangeException. I did point these things out and tell you some idea to solve the problems- did you read and understand all the answer?